# If we have a square matrix thats invertible, do its row and column space coincide?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, span

If we have a square matrix thats invertible, do its row and column space coincide?

Regarding an nxn invertible matrix:

-The row space of the matrix is R^n

-The column space of the matrix is R^n

-The rank of the matrix is n

Is this a sufficient way of proving the question, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If we have a square matrix thats invertible, do its row and column space coincide?

Comment: Correspond in which way? The question is not clear to me.

Comment: I meant, do column and row space coincide

Comment: The name "invertible matrix theorem" is probably not standard, and in any case you don't have a theorem statement in your post, just a list of conditions (presumably concerning an invertible $n \times n$ matrix). Please note also that it's good practice to put your question into the body of your post. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Suppose you have a matrix $ \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $, and it is known to be full rank. Therefore, the number of basis vectors for the column space $ C(\mathbf{A}) $ and the row space $ C(\mathbf{A}^\text{T}) $ is the same, namely $ n $, and these (not necessarily identical) bases span $ \mathbb{R}^n $, so $ C(\mathbf{A}) = \mathbb{R}^n $, and $ C(\mathbf{A}^\text{T}) = \mathbb{R}^n $. It follows that $ C(\mathbf{A}) = C(\mathbf{A}^\text{T}) $. Note, however, that this is a special case that is true only when the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Does this property apply to all invertible matrices or just to invertible square matrices?

Comment: @ThomasHegarty we usually assume that all invertible matrices are square

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$The row space and column space of an $n \times n$ matrix are not generally *equal*, e.g.,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\text{row space} = \{0\} \times \Reals,\quad
\text{column space} = \Reals \times \{0\}.
$$
The row space and column space of an $n \times n$ matrix do always have the same *dimension*, however, and if this dimension is $n$, then each space is equal to $\Reals^{n}$.